# CPLEX MIP warm start seems slow down the program?

Tags: integer-programming, cplex, warm-start

I have been working on a combinatorial optimization problem which can be modeled as an integer linear programming. I implemented it as a c++ project in visual studio 2017 and CPLEX1271. With the hope that my program would run faster, I use MIPStart to provide cplex a feasible solution. But the running time changed from 49s to 140s. All I did is providing a feasible solution to cplex, according to the [answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-does-a-warm-start-work-in-lp-mip/1328?tdsourcetag=s_pctim_aiomsg), it cannot hurt the running time. Can anyone explain it?

**UPDATE1**: The log shows that cplex accept the solution.

**UPDATE2**: I've tested on hundreds of instances. It turned out that a warm start sometimes slows down cplex and at other times it accelerates cplex.

Comment: Can you post the log that cplex prints before and after?

Comment: @prubin has addressed this here : https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/how-to-use-warm-start-to-solve-mips-efficiently/2935#2935

Comment: @Kuifje I didn't add the time to generate a feasible solution. I only count the time consumed by cplex.

Comment: @MengfanMa Read prubin's  answer carefully : he explains why warm starting may result in a longer running time.

Comment: @Kuifje I got it. But I think the answer is too short to get a full understanding. I was wondering if there is any other material on this topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the solution you provided is not very good (i.e., it's far from the global optimum), it often leads the branch-and-bound algorithm down a different path, which ends up slowing down the overall solution time.

MIP solvers are very good in figuring this stuff out by themselves, so the best use of warm-start nowadays is when we solve many similar problems sequentially.

Comment: What do you mean by “use of warm start when we solve many similar problems”?

Comment: This is part of many algorithms, e.g., a feasibility pump, where we only change the objective, or we fix some variables, or add a couple of constraints per iteration. In that case, the solution of problem $i+1$ is very likely to be very similar to the one of problem $i$.